# Raills app is sending a blank pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my rails app I have a ***STATIC*** pdf here "../public/camp.pdf" visitors can download it, but when they do the file size is extremely small and the pdf wont open. I think my rails app is sending a blank pdf. Any ideas?

```
def download_1
  send_data '/camp.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf', :filename => "camp.pdf"
end
```

View:

```
<%= link_to 'PDF', home_download_1_path %>
```

**EDIT**: contents of the pdf is only this "/REGLAS_DE_CARBONO_MEXICO2.pdf"

Comment: try add `x_sendfile: true` and use `send_file` instead `send_data`

Comment: what size is the pdf once donwloaded?

Comment: Open the "pdf" in a text editor and tell us if you see anything interesting.

Comment: interesting the contents of the pdf are this "/REGLAS_DE_CARBONO_MEXICO2.pdf"

Comment: Is the PDF generated by the app? Or a static asset?

Comment: this pdf is a static asset in the public folder

Comment: If you fully qualify the path in the send_data does it work? (i.e. /home/user/files/pdf/camp.pdf instead of just camp.pdf)

Comment: ^ no that sends me to localhost:3000/home/ (_rest of my file location)/camp.pdf

Comment: What about "/public/camp.pdf"?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46871/discussion-between-eabraham-and-alain-goldman)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:

The answer is to use an HTML5 download attribute:

```
<a href="/camp.pdf" download="name_of_downloaded_file.pdf"></a>
```

Comment: that links to it but it wont download it just links to it